# Allow user to change default text in tkinter entry widget.

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a python script that requires the user to enter the name of a folder. For most cases, the default will suffice, but I want an entry box to appear that allows the user to over-ride the default. Here's what I have:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
def main():
    #some stuff
    def getFolderName():
        master = Tk()
        folderName = Entry(master)
        folderName.pack()
        folderName.insert(END, 'dat' + time.strftime('%m%d%Y'))
        folderName.focus_set()
        createDirectoryName = folderName.get()
        def callback():
            global createDirectoryName
            createDirectoryName = folderName.get()
            return 
        b = Button(master, text="OK and Close", width=10, command=callback)
        b.pack()
        mainloop()
        return createDirectoryName
    getFolderName()

   #other stuff happens....
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I know next to nothing about tkInter and have 2 questions.

1. Is over-riding the default entry using `global createDirectoryName` within the callback function the best way to do this?
2. How can I make the button close the window when you press it. 
   I've tried

   ```
   def callback():
       global createDirectoryName
       createDirectoryName = folderName.get()
       master.destroy
   ```

but that simply destroys the window upon running the script.

Comment: Why are all your functions nested?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how experienced are you in Tkinter, but I suggest you use classes.

```
try:
    from tkinter import * #3.x
except:
    from Tkinter import * #2.x


class anynamehere(Tk): #you can make the class inherit from Tk directly, 
    def __init__(self): #__init__ is a special methoed that gets called anytime the class does 
        Tk.__init__(self) #it has to be called __init__
        #further code here e.g.
        self.frame = Frame()
        self.frame.pack()
        self.makeUI()
        self.number = 0 # this will work in the class anywhere so you don't need global all the time
    def makeUI(self):
        #code to make the UI
        self.number = 1 # no need for global
        #answer to question No.2
        Button(frame, command = self.destroy).pack()


anyname = anynamehere() #remember it alredy has Tk
anyname.mainloop()
```

Also why do you want to override the deafult Entry behavior ?
The solution would be to make another button and bind a command to it like this

```
    self.enteredtext = StringVar()
    self.entry = Entry(frame, textvariable = self.enteredtext)
    self.entry.pack()
    self.button = Button(frame, text = "Submit", command = self.getfolder, #someother options, check tkitner documentation for full list)
    self.button.pack()
def getfolder(self): #make the UI in one method, command in other I suggest
    text = self.enteredtext.get()
    #text now has whats been entered to the entry, do what you need to with it
```